# Why Emission Shader looks different from Solid View Flat Texture?

Tags: rendering, emission

in Blender 2.81, Emission Shader looks just same to Solid View - Flat - Texture

[image]

(Left is Solid View, Right is Material Preview with Emission Shader. Earing is PBR)

However, Emission shader looks slightly different in other versions.

[image]

(Left is Solid View, Right is Material Preview with Emission Shader.)

like this picture, Emission shader looks like a little bleached. Color is slightly different with original texture.

All Nodes are Same in Both Versions, and Render settings are not changed from default at all.

If you created blender file in Blender 2.81 once, you're able to open it in other versions and still looks fine in Material Preview.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: Check Render Properties > Color Management > View Transform. It should be "Standard" (the default is "Filmic" which makes colors look dull).

Comment: Thanks a lot 

Comment: @scurest this may actually solve some problems I was having with a certain ad on!